Dynamics GP C# Addin for Desktop and WebClient
I have a GP Addin in C# using Microsoft.Dexterity.Bridge and Microsoft.Dexterity.Applications references.
Everything works perfectly in the desktop client. However, I need guidance on making the code functional for the Web Client. Here’s an example of the issue:
// Does not trigger for the web client
var SeriesPost = Dynamics.Forms.PmSeriesPost.PmSeriesPost;
((WindowProxy)SeriesPost).OpenAfterOriginal += new EventHandler(SeriesPost_OpenAfterOriginal);

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
The events I’m currently handling are:

WindowProxy OpenAfterOriginal
WindowProxy ActivateAfterOriginal
Some datetime field change events

Many thanks
S
